# Android - How does it run and how to use eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

This is probably two questions in one....

Firstly i wonder how does android run the code, is it step by step. The reason i ask this is because at the moment what i am trying to do is decrypt an image and them display it. However, the problem i think is that the code is adding the bitmap image too fast before it is decrypted. Should it run the code line by line?

Secondly Eclipse gives stack error etc but i dont know how to read the stack, is there a way to set it to just say this is the line in the code which is causing the problem?

thanks

EDIT

```
      DesEncrypter encrypter = new DesEncrypter();
      File Directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Temp");
      FileInputStream iFile = new FileInputStream(new File("/sdcard/Images/"+Id+".jpg"));
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Directory+"/"+Id+".jpg");
      encrypter.frontDecrypt(iFile, fos);       
      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Temp/"+Id+".jpg");
      if(file.exists()){
         bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Temp/"+Id+".jpg");
      }
      else{
         bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar);
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

This code seems to work now and then, i think sometimes the bm isnt added correctly. Even if there is no image it should add one from the resource but does not do so.

Comment: If you edit your post to include the code you have a question about and the content of the stacktrace, we will be better able to help you.

Comment: Its not really a particular code its just over all, i will add some to assist with the bitmap issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously code is executed line by line but there are some methods that runs async so they return immediately but execution still continues

Answer (score 1):

You could probably learn more about what's going wrong if you don't swallow the exception like you're doing:

```
try {
  // stuff...
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Instead, at least log the exception:

```
private static final String TAG = "MyClass";

try {
  // stuff...
 }  catch (Exception e) 
 {  
    android.util.Log.w(TAG, e);
 }
```

Comment: The catch is suppose to be only after the first five lines sorry put it in the wrong place in that code, but its the code below that isnt running, the bitmap isnt being decoded i think

Comment: It's really hard to try and diagnose what's wrong if you're only going to paste in select pieces of code. I still recommend logging the exception, because it's quite likely that an exception that's being swallowed is causing subsequent failures in your call to setImageBitmap().

Answer (score 0):

You can always run your application with the debugger and go step by step. Set a breakpoint somewhere on your code and run the application with the debugger in eclipse...